# Converting Python project to .exe file with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, exe, executable, cx-freeze, setup.py

I have a problem about cx_Freeze.

Firstly, I want to share my python project folder: 
[project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8BAK.png)

Application.py imports LiveTable.py and Email.py.
My console project is running without any error. I use some modules such as requests, smtplib, lxml.html..

But I am really confused about writing setup.py file for cx.Freeze

[Current setup.py file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogYNT.png)

I've read many questions and watched lots of youtube videos. Everybody writes different code. How can I fill setup.py  ?

Comment: you can user Auto PY to EXE to convert you .py code to exe. have a look here https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

Comment: Thanks for answer but now there is a specific problem. When I start the exe file, it returns traceback like that  https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/688852440040341589/692644340492664853/as.PNG  .  But I import smtplib for my project . Also I tried it manually with pyinstaller and I faced similar error .

Answer (score 0):

Check the [docummentation of cxfreeze scripts](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/script.html).

There you can find exactly how to set up the library.